# Calculadora ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy realizando un pequeño ejercicio de operaciones consumiendo un Web Service, pero no encuentro la manera de poder mostrar el resultado en la vista, no estoy usando Model.

controlador

```
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int primero, int segundo)
{
    // Creación de un objeto de referencia del servicio web  
    ServiceReference1.CalculatorSoapClient multi = new ServiceReference1.CalculatorSoapClient();

    // llama y almacena el resultado del servicio web en la variable  
    var multiplicac = multi.Multiply(primero, segundo);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

puedes pasar el valor a la vista de la siguiente forma:

```
public ActionResult NombreView()
{
  ViewData["multiplicac"] = multi.Multiply(primero, segundo);
    return View();
}
```

y luego en la vista lo puedes usar haciendo:

```
   @Html.Encode(ViewData["multiplicac"].ToString())
```